# turn off warning in leksah

Tags: haskell, leksah

For a good reason, I want to temporally turn of the warnings about the missing type level signature in the leksah IDE.

I changed the flags to ghc cabal file and the warnings are absent when I run "cabal install" from the console.

However, if I build the same project in the leksah IDE, the warnings are still shown.

How can I turn off  "Warning: Top-level binding with no type signature:" in the leksah IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the desired option to the cabal file:

ghc-options: -fno-warn-missing-signatures

Answer (score 8):

It is much better to disable warnings only in a single file than in whole project. 
Use

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-missing-signatures #-}
```

pragma on the top of a file.